# Why do monerod and monero-wallet-cli have mine commands?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cpu-mining, monerod

Looking at **--help**, they each have a **start_mining** and **stop_mining** command. **monerod** includes an argument for an address. How are these different from **cpuminer-multi**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you type the start_mining command in monero-wallet-cli (or simplewallet in older versions), the wallet software forwards that instruction to the daemon together with the address that is  currently open. The demon then starts mining and sends the rewards to that address (in case it can find a block).

If you start_mining in monerod, you have to specify the address where you want the rewards sent. Other than that it works the same way.

cpuminer-multi is a piece of software that is used to mine on pools. You have to specify the pool URL and an address to start mining (there are a few other options like the number of threads to use).

Comment: Fine answer.
Do you recommend mining with monero-wallet-cli? I'm trying, but it doesn't seem to send status messages when it's mining. I don't really know if it's making progress or just sitting there.

Comment: Since the mining is being done in the daemon, you see the status over there. You have to use the command **show_hr**. Type help inside monerod to see the full list of available commands.

Answer (score 0):

It is mainly used for solo mining, while cpuminer is mainly for pool mining. I assume that cpuminer is optimized for mining