# How to tell if start_mining is mining

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mining, mining-pools, cpu-mining, nodes

When I type start_mining, there is no visible indication that anything is happening. Can anyone help with with advice on how to see a visual indication that something is happening?

Note, *balance* says 0. Typing *stop_mining* says "Mining stopped in Daemon"

I am using a remote node with *monero-wallet-cli*.

In the following post [Why do monerod and monero-wallet-cli have mine commands?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2377/why-do-monerod-and-monero-wallet-cli-have-mine-commands), it says that the *show_hr* command can be used but this relies on monerod running which, given that I am using a remote node, it doesn't apply.

Comment: show_hr  (heck try 'help' from the daemon)  with CPU mining, wait at least 6 months to see if you got a jackpot winning lottery ticket.  My advice is to NOT use the daemon miner and use a CPU miner and point to a pool.  Been a while, but you need a fully *local* node and fully sync'd to mine from daemon.  Can't point to a remote daemon.

Comment: @Dave It should be possible to mine locally using a Remote Node. See https://coinguides.org/remote-nodes-monero-wallet-gui-cli/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the daemon (monerod) logs. When the node is mining, it prints logs to show it's mining.

> it says that the show_hr command can be used but this relies on monerod running which, given that I am using a remote node, it doesn't apply.

The mining is happening on the daemon monerod (remote or local) and `show_hr` will indeed show you your mining hashrate.

Comment: If I execute ./ monerod then it starts syncing the blockchain which I don't want to do as its currently 41GB and I don't have the space. How can I run monerod without syncing the blockchain?

Comment: ./monerod --offline

Comment: ./monerod --offline (THIS WORKS!)